# Proof of Heine Borel, not in general topology

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I will take a remedial exam for Real Analysis and studying the concepts again. So I tried to proof Heine-Borel Theorem but there is some problems and I need help or verification. There are some proofs, yet they all are in general topological space which I can not understand with my current knowledge.

**Heine-Borel Theorem in Tao Analysis II**: Consider (${R^n},d$) where d is one of the metrics $d_{l^1},d_{l^2}, d_{l^\infty}$. A subset $E \subset\ {R^n}$ is compact if and only if E is bounded and closed.

**Proof**:
$\Leftarrow$ Assume E is bounded and closed. Let $x_n$ be a sequence in E. Since E is bounded, $x_n$ converges thus has a convergent subsequence which converges in E, since E is closed (E contains limit points). Since we did not specify $x_n$, it is arbitrary and every sequence has convergent subsequence, thus E is sequentially compact. This implies compactness, thus E is compact.

$\Rightarrow$: E is compact, means that sequentially compact, implies every $x_n$ in E has a convergent subsequence. This is where I got total lost. I have ideas about it but can not construct the formal way. (I will add them to comments not to make the question too long.)

Also, we know that ${R^n}$ is closed under one of those metrics (We can assume that, I know how to prove it). I don't know if this is useful for this proof, but you can assume that I know that if necessary.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know that there are proofs in the website, but this is not just a question, also a verification of my own thinking. So, please do not downvote and be kind...

Comment: I don't think you should bring in sequential compactness. You should argue with open covers.

Comment: Alright, but why?

Comment: Whether you should use sequences probably depends on what you already know at that point in the textbook.  If, for example, you already know "a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ has a convergent subsequence", then you are free to use that, as you did in $\Rightarrow$. What is left to prove in your attempt?  From "every sequence in $E$ has a subsequence convergent in $E$" you have to deduce "$E$ is bounded" and "$E$ is closed".  Try to do that.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you, I am on it.

Comment: @jrsmith_of_math You wrote _“Let $x_n$ be a sequence in E. Since E is bounded,$x_n$ converges […]”_ This is not true (but what follows is).

Comment: The answer to your question to geetha290km (who was never notified of your question as you did not address it to them) is that in general topological spaces compactness and sequential compactness are not equivalent, with compactness being more powerful. It is wise in general to view compactness in terms of its actual definition. It will give you a better idea of what compactness is and how to handle it. That said, this question is specifically about $\Bbb R^n$, where they are equivalent, so you are fine making use of that fact, provided it has already been proven.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to recall that "$E$ is compact $\implies E$ is closed and bounded" is equivalent to "$E$ is not closed or not bounded $\implies E$ is not compact", which is equivalent to "($E$ is not closed $\implies E$ is not compact) and ($E$ is not bounded $\implies E$ is not compact)".